# multiplying int to double c#

Tags: c#, .net, operators

I want to to multiply textbox1(int) by textbox2(double) and return a double in textbox3
Im doing an Invoice app and need to multiply quantity by rate to get amount so far I have this...

```
private void textbox2_TextChanged(object sender, system.EventArgs e)
{
 int32 qty = int32.Parse(Textbox1.text);
 Double rate = Double.Parse(Textbox2.text);
 Double amt = qty * rate;
 textbox3.text = amt.ToString();
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the problem/error you are facing?

Comment: Same question as above and also is there any reason that you could not parse them both to doubles?

Comment: just simply use double on your qty

Comment: One thing you might want to think about is how you handle things if the textbox doesn't contain numbers (eg somebody writes text in there). For this reason you might wnat to look at `TryParse` methods instead of plain `Parse`.

Comment: @BizApps: I don't think that will make a difference to anything...

Comment: In the textbox3 I get 40 and not 40.00,

Comment: I also get a runtime error that the qty input string was not in the correct format

Comment: You can use Format providers http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx

Comment: @JoseRivas Your only error is that you are not properly validating input. The key rule is: _"input is not valid unless it's proven to be valid"_.

Comment: You should not be using doubles in the first place if this is an invoice; use doubles to solve *physics* problems. Use decimal to solve financial problems; that is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to check whether the first text box is not empty or blank spaces.
Then if your first text box is empty or blank space then give appropriate message to user.

Try the example below:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Textbox1.text))
{
    int qty = Int32.Parse(Textbox1.text);
    double rate = Double.Parse(Textbox2.text);
    Textbox3.text = (rate* (double) qty).ToString();
}
else
{
    //Give appropriate message to user for entering quantity in textbox 1
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting 4 * 10.00 = 40 and not 40.00

Comment: okay I used this but changed double to decimal and it worked

Comment: you can directly cast or formate your string like this... Textbox3.text = amt.ToString("0.00");

Comment: for this review this link... http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Casting `qty` to `double` is really not necessary. Result of `double * int` is always `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
  textBox3.Text = (Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text) * Double.Parse(textBox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off. When you are dealing with money, always use decimal, not double.
And with decimals, there is always the problem with users using both comma and dot as decimal separator.

This code worked for me:

```
    int qty = Int32.Parse("2");
    Decimal rate = Decimal.Parse("3.14".Replace(".", ","));
    Decimal amt = qty * rate;
    Console.WriteLine(amt);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that code only work for locales where the decimal seperator is a comma?

Comment: Yes. It is better to use proper culture handling if you target multiple locales.